# Finding the significance of certain questions in a survey

Tags: statistical-significance, predictor, multivariable

My company performs a Go/No-Go questionnaire to determine whether or not to go after a particular opportunity.  In this questionnaire is a series of 14 yes/no questions.  We have accumulated a reasonable amount of data and I am attempting to determine the significance of the questions asked (NOTE: I understand that "significance" carries a specific definition in statistics.  I am using the word using the more lay-person definition).  We have the results of several dozen questionnaires for both won and lost opportunities.

I would like to try to determine:

1. Are specific questions more apt to indicate a win/loss?
2. Are specific questions essentially worthless for determining a win/loss?
3. Are there certain combinations of questions which carry a particularly accurate indication of the likely outcome?  I mean this to be different from the previous two questions in that while many questions may carry significance, some combinations of questions may be particularly good at predicting the outcome when taken together.

I have only a rudimentary knowledge of statistics so I hope that there is a way to run the numbers to try to glean the information I am looking for.  Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the relevance of any individual teacher you should look at the [Chi-Squared test for independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_test#Chi-square_test_for_independence_and_homogeneity_in_tables). This will tell you likelihood of your questions being statistically significantly related to your outcomes.

In terms of looking at group effects there are lots of techniques to do this. The simplest (in my opinion) to understand is the [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). There are lots of other models like [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) that also model this problem.